# Tabhost not showing tabs

Tags: java, android

I follow tutorial found on internet, but it seems that doesn't work...

I get Tab 1 always opened, that is okay, but I don't see TABS menu up...

Here is my code:

Main2Activity:

```
public class Main2Activity  extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        // create the TabHost that will contain the Tabs
        TabHost tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

        tabs.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");

        spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec.setIndicator("Analog Clock");
        tabs.addTab(spec);

        spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tag2");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        spec.setIndicator("DigitalClock");
        tabs.addTab(spec);

        spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tag3");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        spec.setIndicator("Button");
        tabs.addTab(spec);
    }
```

Content_main2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <AnalogClock android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
            <DigitalClock android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Do Nothing"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

[This is how it looks when i run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI0vz.jpg)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918488/android-how-do-you-set-up-the-tabhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with:

```
setContentView(R.layout.content_main2);
```

I was calling activity_main2, but don't know why when I call activity_main2 don't get content_main2.

I have in Activity_main2.xml:

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main2" />
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `seperate activity` for `each tab`. as said by "intelliJ". create `seperate activity` and `seperate xml` file for each `tab` and then add your analog digital and button in each activity respectively. say in `activity1` add `analog` and in `activity2` add `digital` and so on.